# Can't get my text colours to change in print css

Tags: html, css, colors

I have a drupal page that needs some custom formatting when printing, so I put it all in a separate print css. Most of it is working, except for my text colours.

I have tried all selectors that are associated with the text, even the `*`-selector. But none of them change the colour.

What does work, is changing the colour in the firefox editor, on my real page.

part of the HTML, the innermost element needs to be changed to black in this case:

```
<div class="field-label">Productgroep:&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even">
               <a href="/taxonomy/term/43" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel">Fruit</a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS I tried:

```
art-post-inner art-article, /* one of the wrappers */
field-items, /* the outer div */
a, /* select all links, I have also tried all the different states of a link (hovered, visited, etc) */
* /* select all */
{
    color: #000;
}
```

If you need any more info, please do ask.

Comment: have tried by adding the !important like color: #000 !important;

Comment: I have never heard of that `!important` keyword. But it works! Please add that as an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `!important` at the `color: #000 !important;`

what it does

CSS rules marked !important take precedence over later rules. Normally in CSS the rules work from top to bottom, so if you assigned a new style to an element further down the style sheet or in a secondary style sheet then the later rule would take precedence. !important ensures that this rule has precedence.